# Using hpacucli to disable auto logical volume disabling when failed

Tags: raid, hp, hardware-raid

By default, when a physical drive fails in an HP RAID array, the controller takes the logical volume offline to prevent data loss, instead of taking it in "degraded" status like LSI/Adaptec does and waiting for hot swap replacement of the failed drive and rebuild the array.

Is there a way to set it so it won't disable the logical volume when a single drive fails in the array and have it waiting for drive hot swap to rebuild the array by using hpacucli?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong. A single drive failure does NOT disable an HP Smart Array Logical Drive. They are only disabled if there's data loss.

A failed drive or drives in a fault-tolerant array will continue running up to the point where the array can no longer provide any data protection. E.g. Two drives failed in a RAID5 array will mean data loss.